# How to combine multiple trained models into one and use it to predict?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, model

I have a time series data frame with 100 rows and 1000+ columns. The columns are independent of each other.  I am running the ARIMA model on each of these columns. So, it is like running 1000+ ARIMA analysis.

I have written a piece of code that loops through the columns of the training set and fits the ARIMA model on every column as per the p,d,q parameters provided. Although, it looks like as the model trains further through the columns, it forgets what was learnt before and only uses the training results from the last trained column to predict on test. (Which is causing the predictions to overfit on the test set).

Is there a way I can combine the learnings of all the trained models together and use it to make predictions on my test set? For example, for dataset below: since I am training ARIMA on each column, I have 4 trained columns. I want to somehow maybe find an average between all these trained models and combine it into one model (Model(x)) and use the Model(x) to further forecast.

Sample data frame looks like this:

```
date                        Col 1     Col 2     Col 3      Col 4
2001-07-21 10:00:00+05:00    45          51       31         3  
2001-07-21 10:15:00+05:00    46          50       32         3
2001-07-21 10:30:00+05:00    47          51       34         7
2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00    50          50       33         9
2001-07-21 11:00:00+05:00    55          51       32         8
2001-07-21 11:15:00+05:00    52          73       34         11
2001-07-21 11:30:00+05:00    51          72       30         14
```

The code I have implemented is: (I realize this is not the right way)

```
#training set inclues all columns except the last and test set includes only last column.
train = df.iloc[:, :-1]
test = df.iloc[:,-1:]


order = (1,2,3) 

for col in train.columns:
  model = ARIMA(train[col], order = order)  #training every column in training set
  model = model.fit()
model.summary()

predictions = model.predict(len(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you loop, you are creating a new ARIMA model and you are fitting it on your column. After your last loop, you only have fitted on your last column and then you are predicting on your test column.

You have to put your predicting inside your for loop.

```
for col in train.columns:
  model = ARIMA(train[col], order = order)  #training every column in training set
  model = model.fit()
  model.summary()
  predictions = model.predict(len(test))
  print(predictions)
```

This will give you predictions based on the fitting of each one of your columns. You could add your predictions to a list to keep track of them and handle your results how you want.

```
predictions_lst = []
for col in train.columns:
  ...
  predictions_lst.append(predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to get predictions based on the fitting of each column. I am looking for a way to somehow get the average of all the trained models and combine it so that it is one single model. And use the combined model for forecasting.